# Issue with JSON serialization in specific configuration in angular application

Tags: angular

some time ago I was using Angular 9 in my application and I decided to update it to version 12. After this I couldn't debug my application using Chrome debugger. It turned out that command "ng serve" was using "development" configuration before and now uses "production" configuration by default.

To enable debugging through chrome debugger over my application I added a specific configuration named "development" and I run application now with configuration written explicitly: ng run --configuration="development".

These settings looks like here:

[image]

and everything was going okay until now when I noticed that both options: "buildOptimizer" and "optimization" are set on true in "production" configuration and after deploy they cause various (invalid) results during JSON serialization in my custom Serializer (I had to create custom Serializer due to not-flatten data). If I turn these options off, serialization works fine.

Do you have any ideas why these options may affect serialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a root cause of this issue.
It is fault of array.map() and it looks like setup: optimization + buildOptimizer in pair cause improper behavior of map() method (maybe on account of parallelism). I replaced it with brute-force foreach approach:

```
export class A
{
  children: A[] = [];
  param: string = '';
}
```

Approach with map (unexpected result after prod-build optimization):

```
toJson(input: A): string {
  let children =
    '"children": ['
    + input.children.map((child) => `{ ${this.toJson(child)} }` );
    + '],'

  let param = `"param": ${input.param}`;
  return '{' + children + param + '}';
}
```

Approach with foreach:

```
toJson(input: A): string {
  let children = '"children": [';
  let childrenArray: string[] = [];
  input.children.forEach((child) => {
    childrenArray.push(`${this.toJson(child)}`);
  });
  children += childrenArray.join(',');
  children += '],';

  let param = `"param": ${input.param}`;
  return '{' + children + param + '}';
}
```